# How to extend standard Golang unexported struct type?

Tags: go

consider this working sample code, which extends (not exactly) the

```
type multiWriter struct {
    writers []Writer
}
```

from `io` package, to add just two methods named `Remove` and `Append` to manipulate internal slice `writers`:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    w1, e := os.Create("file1.txt")
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    w2, e := os.Create("file2.txt")
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    mw := MultiWriter(w1, w2)
    data := []byte("Hello ")
    _, e = mw.Write(data)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    var m *multiWriter = mw.(*multiWriter)
    m.Remove(w2)
    w2.Close()
    w3, e := os.Create("file3.txt")
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    m.Append(w3)
    data = []byte("World ")
    _, e = mw.Write(data)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    w3.Close()
    w1.Close()
}
func (t *multiWriter) Remove(writers ...io.Writer) {
    for i := len(t.writers) - 1; i > 0; i-- {
        for _, v := range writers {
            if t.writers[i] == v {
                t.writers = append(t.writers[:i], t.writers[i+1:]...)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
func (t *multiWriter) Append(writers ...io.Writer) {
    t.writers = append(t.writers, writers...)
}

type multiWriter struct {
    writers []io.Writer
}

func (t *multiWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    for _, w := range t.writers {
        n, err = w.Write(p)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        if n != len(p) {
            err = io.ErrShortWrite
            return
        }
    }
    return len(p), nil
}

var _ stringWriter = (*multiWriter)(nil)

func (t *multiWriter) WriteString(s string) (n int, err error) {
    var p []byte // lazily initialized if/when needed
    for _, w := range t.writers {
        if sw, ok := w.(stringWriter); ok {
            n, err = sw.WriteString(s)
        } else {
            if p == nil {
                p = []byte(s)
            }
            n, err = w.Write(p)
        }
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        if n != len(s) {
            err = io.ErrShortWrite
            return
        }
    }
    return len(s), nil
}

// MultiWriter creates a writer that duplicates its writes to all the
// provided writers, similar to the Unix tee(1) command.
func MultiWriter(writers ...io.Writer) io.Writer {
    w := make([]io.Writer, len(writers))
    copy(w, writers)
    return &multiWriter{w}
}

// stringWriter is the interface that wraps the WriteString method.
type stringWriter interface {
    WriteString(s string) (n int, err error)
}
```

is there any concise way to do this, to add just two methods named `Remove` and `Append` to `io.MultiWriter`?

Comment: What do you mean by the "only way"? What other ways are you expecting?

Comment: @icza: not to copy all std lib.

Comment: You can't define methods for types in other packages. A code can only define methods for types being in the same package.

Comment: @icza: so this is the only way, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. _(padding...)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define methods for types in other packages. A code can only define methods for types being in the same package.

[Spec: Method declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)

> The type denoted by `T` is called the receiver *base type*; it must not be a pointer or interface type and **it must be declared in the same package as the method**.

So there is no other way to extend the unexported type `io.multiWriter` with methods other than copy its full code and add the methods to your own type.

**Note:** As an implementation note, in your `multiWriter.Remove()` method once you find the removable writer, after reslicing you can "break" (from the inner loop) to omit the rest of the slice:

```
// ...
if t.writers[i] == v {
    t.writers = append(t.writers[:i], t.writers[i+1:]...)
    break
}
// ...
```